# jquery Two selects - remove options of one based on the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select lists built with jstl.  One contains all available people, the other contains applicable people.  I want to remove the applicable people from the all available people list.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chosenList").each(function() {
    $("option", this).each(function(){
      $("#chooseList option[value='"+this+"']").remove();
    });
  });
});
```

I thought the above would work, but it doesn't.  Can someone point out the error of my ways?

Comment: Can you load this, and the two lists (if not in full, in an example format) into http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: never used that before.  Can you access it at this [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/fM2uV/2/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hit this kind of problem before. Change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chosenList").each(function() {
    $("option", $(this)).each(function(){
      $("#chooseList option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").remove();
    });
  });
});
```

Note the `$()` around `this`? That's because `this` is a 'pure' JavaScript object - not a jQuery object, and therefore does not have the `.val()` function. Putting `$()` around it converts it to a jQuery object.

Comment: Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/xfbQg/. @Risu: No problem. Glad to help. I'm addicted to this stuff haha

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chosenList option").each(function() {
      $("#chooseList option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").remove();
  });
});
```

**Edit:** Now that I looked at the code snippet in detail I wonder why you use two nested each functions. I hope you're not having several selects with the ID `#chosenList`... Anyway, I'd say this should work now...

Comment: Took me a few back and forths to see what changed. For those doing the same, @Tomm added `.val()` to the `this` in line 4.

Comment: I think my problem is I followed this example [link](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html) which uses `$().ready()` which I see isn't recommended.  Trying to add my code breaks the functionality.

Comment: Your ready function is fine - read my answer for what is wrong with it.